# int.TryParse returns false when parsing a valid string

Tags: c#

I'm trying to check if a string is a valid number or not. But this returns false. Why.

```
int IsNumber;
var parsed = int.TryParse("9876543210", NumberStyles.Number, null, out IsNumber);

if (parsed)
 {

 }
else
 {

 }
```

Also tried with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat,` instead of `null`.
When debugging, it never hits inside the if condition.

Comment: the maxvalue of a 32-bit integer is  2,147,483,647. use int64/long instead

Comment: try long.TryParse, because int is max 2bilion

Comment: And if `long` doesn't cover the range you want, look at `BigInteger`...

Comment: for the future: i guess you could have find that out by using `int.Parse` and inspect the exception.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work

```
long IsNumber;
var parsed = long.TryParse("9876543210", NumberStyles.Number, null, out IsNumber);

if (parsed)
{

}
else
{

}
```

your code wasn't working because int.Max is 2147483647. If you want to check if all chars in string are digits, you can use [Char.IsDigit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58(v=VS.110).aspx):

```
var number = yourString.All(Char.IsDigit);
```

it will work for numbers bigger than max value of long ( 9223372036854775807)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`BigInteger.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268268(v=vs.110).aspx) Method. `BigInteger` represents an arbitrarily large signed integer.

Add this to using directives at top of page:

```
using System.Numerics;
```

Then:

```
BigInteger IsNumber;
var parsed = BigInteger.TryParse("9876543210", NumberStyles.Integer, null, out IsNumber);

if (parsed)
{

}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it for validation (as you describe it) and you don't need to convert it to number type, use regular expression instead. This regular expression gives you information, whether the string contains numbers only

```
var stringToValidate = "9876543210"
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d$");
if (regex.IsMatch(compare))
{ 
    //validation passed
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `*` (or `+`) there. Also, careful with `\d` - it also matches other numerals, like `౫` for example. If you only want "modern european" numbers, `[0-9]` really works best.